# Spring boot with Hadoop Connection(Hbase)

Tags: java, maven, hbase

I have requirement like ,i need to connect hadoop-hbase in my spring boot code.I have done many examples.But i unable to connect hadoop system.Can you please share working sampleproj hadoop with hbase project using spring boot.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'feedService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hbaseTemplate': Error creating bean with name 'hbaseTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/HbaseConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate]: Factory method 'hbaseTemplate' threw exception with message: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTableInterface**

Thanks in Advance...

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
]
```

Hbase config class

public class HConnection {

```
private String hbasezookeeperquorum = "PRODDMSDN04";// ,proddmsdn02,proddmsdn01
private String hbasezookeeperpropertyclientPort = "2181";
private String hbasemaster = "proddmsdn01:16010";
private String zookeeperznodeparent = "/hbase-unsecure";

private String dmshbasetable="DMSMASTER";
private String dmshbasetableimgfamily="img";
private String  dmshbasetabledatafamily="data";
private String  dmshbasetablemetafamily="meta";
 static Configuration conf;
 
 static Connection connection;
 private String dmsid="1a2c3e0e-8363-4e94-87c9-701029933b37";
private Connection newConnection() {
    

     Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", hbasezookeeperquorum);
            conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", hbasezookeeperpropertyclientPort);
            conf.set("hbase.master", hbasemaster);
            conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", zookeeperznodeparent);
            conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
            System.out.println("conn" + conn.getConfiguration());
            // Instantiate configuration class
            // Instantiate configuration class

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    return conn;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //String fileName = "DMSMASTER";

    System.out.println("Connecting to Hadoop------->");



     connection=new HConnection().newConnection();
    
     FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);

    if (fileSystem instanceof DistributedFileSystem) {
        System.out.println("HDFS is the underlying filesystem");
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        // Connection connection=new HConnection().afterPropertiesSet();

        //new HConnection().searchData(connection);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Other type of file system " + fileSystem.getClass());
        
        System.out.println("Filesystem connected------->");
        

    
}
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();


public Optional<List<Map<String, String>>> searchMetaData(Map<String, String> searchParams)
        throws IOException {
    
    System.out.println("searchParams-------------->"+searchParams);
    

    TableName tablename = TableName.valueOf(dmshbasetable);
    Table table = connection.getTable(tablename);
    System.out.println("Connecting table-------------->"+table);
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(dmshbasetabledatafamily));
    scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(dmshbasetablemetafamily));
    FilterList allFilters = new FilterList(new Filter[0]);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : searchParams.entrySet()) {
        SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(dmshbasetablemetafamily),
                Bytes.toBytes(entry.getKey()), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(entry.getValue()));
        allFilters.addFilter((Filter) filter);
    }
    SingleColumnValueFilter filter2 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(dmshbasetabledatafamily),
            Bytes.toBytes("status"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes("1"));
    allFilters.addFilter((Filter) filter2);
    scan.setFilter((Filter) allFilters);
    ResultScanner resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan);
    Iterator<Result> arr = resultScanner.iterator();
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (arr.hasNext()) {
        Get g = new Get(((Result) arr.next()).getRow());
        Result result = table.get(g);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        NavigableMap<byte[], byte[]> data = result.getFamilyMap(Bytes.toBytes(dmshbasetabledatafamily));
        NavigableMap<byte[], byte[]> metadata = result.getFamilyMap(Bytes.toBytes(dmshbasetablemetafamily));
        data.putAll(metadata);
        for (Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : data.entrySet())
            map.put(new String(entry.getKey()), new String(entry.getValue()));
        list.add(map);
        
    }
    if (list.isEmpty())
        return Optional.empty();
    
    
    
    
    List<JSONObject> jsonObj = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    for(Map<String, String> data : list) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
        jsonObj.add(obj);
    }

    JSONArray test = new JSONArray(jsonObj);

    System.out.println(test.toString());
    
    writeCSV(test.toString());
    
    return Optional.of(list);
}

private void writeCSV(String list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
     try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("hadoopconnection_test.csv"))) {

          StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

          stringbuilder.append("DMSid");

          stringbuilder.append(',');

          stringbuilder.append("Payload");

          stringbuilder.append('\n');

          stringbuilder.append(dmsid);

          stringbuilder.append(',');

          stringbuilder.append(list);

          stringbuilder.append('\n');

          writer.write(stringbuilder.toString());

        System.out.println("Data Imported to CSV successfully Done------->");
          

        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            
          System.out.println(exception.getMessage());

        }
    
}






}
```

Comment: i added  hbase config code above.Please check and do the  needful

Comment: The shown code doesn't use spring-data, or spring-boot at all. So, you should remove it from your dependencies. Asking for external resources or someone to write SpringBoot code for you is off-topic for Stackoverflow